# Jenkins start same docker container with different compose files

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to Jenkins, and I have a project, but there are I need few instances of it, with different configurations, meaning, to run different docker-compose files, due to different mounts / ports, but the rest of the project is the same.

I could not find any information about an issue like this.

if it help:
Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
agent any

environment {
    PATH = "$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
}

stages {
    stage("build docker image"){   
        steps{
            sh """
                docker build . -t application:development --pull=false 
            """
        }
    }
    stage("run compose"){
        steps{
            sh"""
            docker-compose up -d
            """
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! This is possible.
You need to create 2 docker-compose files with different configurations.
Ex:
docker-compose-a.yml
docker-compose-b.yml
Then:

```
pipeline {
agent any

environment {
    PATH = "$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
}

stages {
    stage("build docker image"){   
        steps{
            sh """
                docker build . -t application:development --pull=false 
            """
        }
    }
    stage("run compose"){
        steps{
            sh"""
            docker-compose up -f docker-compose-a.yml -d
            docker-compose up -f docker-compose-b.yml -d
            """
        }
    }
}
```